# How do you change a user in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, psql

```
postgres=# \du
                         List of roles
Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 

-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
 shorturl  | Superuser                                      | {}

postgres=# create database shorturl;
CREATE DATABASE

postgres=# \c shorturl;
You are now connected to database "shorturl" as user "postgres".

shorturl=#
```

My preference was to use database ***shorturl*** being the user ***shorturl*** and not ***postgres***. How do I change the same?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When you display the `psql` online help by entering `\?` you can see:

```
Connection
  \c[onnect] {[DBNAME|- USER|- HOST|- PORT|-] | conninfo}
                         connect to new database (currently "postgres")
```

So you need to use:

```
\c shorturl shorturl
```

Comment: That worked very well. Thanks. Could you provide the reference link ?

Comment: @AbhinavRalhan: you can find that [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) or - as I have mentioned in my answer - by entering `\?` from within `psql`

Comment: didn't work for me, another user has a password, when I try to change with this command he say auth failed. (edit): nevermind, I found it haha, using `set role`

Answer (score 6):

Another option, if you're already connected to database `shorturl`, is the command:

```
SET ROLE shorturl;
```

The benefits of that command are that it's not tied to psql, and that you can change user "midstream" of your work.